# jquery Highlight text or character in textbox with different color

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

i am trying to highlight words and characters in textbox with different colors.. same as it is when we use find function on browser to search any word and browser highlights the all word  is there any jquery plugin which help me to highlights given text or character in text box

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of plugins out there. Try one of these: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that just with a textarea you'll need to use a third party solution such as:

http://www.tinymce.com/
http://ckeditor.com/

or write one yourself which is quite time consuming